# can I use composite key as partition key in Dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table includes 3 fields:

```
uuid: string
m: string
s: string
timestamp
```

the UUID is the partition key and timestamp is sort key. I need to build a function to take `m` and `s` as input and return `uuid` to users. In order to improve query performance, I am thinking to create a global secondary index to include `m` and `s` as partition key.

But I can't find a way to create a composite partition key. Do I have to use `m` as partition key and `s` as sort key for the global secondary index? What other solutions I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re always looking for an exact match of m and s; you can create a single partition key with is just those two concatenases together.

Comment: I am not always looking for m and s match. I need to show them separately.

Comment: You can still return the attributes m and s separately; but query on the concatenation.

Comment: so you mean create an additional one only for partition key?

Comment: Yes. It assumes that concatenation  of M&S is unique though